Is the good life a happy one?
I am curious whether the good life is also, somewhat by necessity, a happy one? I am basing this off of the concept that happiness is not merely feeling good all the time, but rather in the sense of eudaimonia or flourishing.
In that sense, is there any arguement that the good life can also be unhappy? According to Aristotle I guess not?

Maybe relevant Wolfgang Pleger, The Good Life: An Introduction to Ethics (Palgrave, 2023)

And yes; see EN, 1095a: "we may almost say that the great majority of mankind are agreed about this; for both the multitude and persons of refinement speak of it as Happiness, and conceive ‘the good life’ or ‘doing well’ to be the same thing as ‘being happy.’ "

I would say that happiness is not a goal, it is one of the outcomes of wellbeing or flourishing. Could you be sick and be happy, or well and unhappy?
